# Iterating through a jQuery array

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I'm trying to iterate through an array and assign values to an element as such:

```
<tool>hammer</tool>

var tools = ["screwdriver", "wrench", "saw"];
var i;
for (i=0; i < tools.length; ++i){
$("tool").delay(300).fadeOut().delay(100).html(tools[i]).fadeIn();
};
```

However this doesn't seem to work as only "saw" is assigned as the html value and keeps fading in and out.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: All the delays and fades fire at the same time overwriting everything with the last value only

Comment: @adeneo  tool is a custom html element. got it. so if i include them in separate lines it should work?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tc1q1vv7/ (http://jsfiddle.net/tc1q1vv7/1/)

Comment: @adeneo how do i fire them consecutively?

Comment: @JaredFarrish Thanks! If you include it as an answer, I'll accept it!

Comment: Logic is all wrong... the loop is done almost instantly. Animations are asynchronous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`jQuery.delay()`](https://api.jquery.com/delay/) pauses between *effects queued items*, so your `.html()` is being set instantaneously. Hence, you only see `saw`.

A solution is to scrap the `for` loop and "loop" against the length of the array, setting the `tool` text to the next *first* item in the array (as you remove it). However, you need to do this inside the context of the queue, so you can use the `.fadeOut()` callback to do this.

Wrap all this in a function (here, I immediately invoke it but give it a label, `a`, so it can be referenced, it's not *anonymous*) and pass that to `.fadeIn()` at the end so it continues the loop until the array is empty.

```
var tools = ["screwdriver", "wrench", "saw"];

(function a(){
    if (tools.length) {
        $("tool").delay(300).fadeOut(0, function(){
            $(this).html(tools.shift());
        }).delay(100).fadeIn(a);
    }
})();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tc1q1vv7/1/